# Plotting two circles and finding their intersection points

Tags: plotting, manipulate, regions, geometry

> I would like to generate the two circle graphic shown below:

[image]

> As the first step, I want to make the first circle with center `(0,0)` and diameter of `100 mm` by using the program that follows:

[image]

But, I feel confused when I will make second circle with center of distance `85 mm` and diameter of `140 mm`.

My questions:

1. Is there another better technique to make the first circle and the second circle? Also, please advice me how to get points in both circles?
2. How to find the intersection point between the first circle and the second circle?

Comment: Can you use `RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, 50], Circle[{85, 0}, 70]]` to find the intersection, and then `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 50], Circle[{85, 0}, 70], PointSize[Large], 
  RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, 50], Circle[{85, 0}, 70]]}]` to plot it?

Comment: [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) was introduced in v10. For earlier versions see [`Circle-Circle Intersection`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) in [`Wolfram MathWorld`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com)

Answer (score 8):

## 1.

You can use the `Circle` Expression to create your circles instead of plotting points. Then poke the circle expressions into `Graphics` to create the plot. (Since you want axes, we set the Axis option to True)

```
circle1 = Circle[{0, 0}, 50];
circle2 = Circle[{85, 0}, 70];
Graphics[{circle1, circle2}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Two outlines of circles intersecting each other overlaid onto a pair of axes]

## 2.

To find the intersection of the circle we can use the formulas for the two circles and the solve function

```
equation1 = x^2 + y^2 == 50^2;
equation2 = (x - 85)^2 + y^2 == 70^2;
solutions = Solve[{equation1, equation2}]
```

[image: The solutions to the above formula as a list of lists of rules]

To convert that into a nice set of coordinates, we use `Part` which can be written as `[[` `]]`. It is similar to indexing in other programming languages.

```
coords = solutions[[ All, All, 2]]
```

Then we generate points using `Point` and `Map` (which can also be written as `/@`) to generate Point expressions to insert into the Graphics function. Map (when written as `/@`) wraps every item of the top level expression on the right hand side with the function supplied on the left hand side.

```
points = Point /@ coords
```

The we join our points with the circles `Join` to feed to the `Graphics` function similar to what we did in part 1

```
Graphics[Join[{circle1, circle2}, points], Axes -> True]
```

[image: Two circles intersecting with their intersections highlighted with little black dots]

To make the points easier to see, we can make them larger with the `PointSize` Graphics directive

```
Graphics[Join[{PointSize[Large], circle1, circle2}, points], Axes -> True]
```

[image: The same two circles intersecting, with their intersections highlighted with large black dots]

Comment: Your `Circle` expressions have the wrong radius; they should be `Circle[{0, 0}, 50]; Circle[{85, 0}, 70];`.

Comment: @The Square Cow, technically it works. and for question no. 1, how to get points in circle1 and circle2? as on my previous program, e.g. circle1= {{100., 0.}, {98.4808, 17.3648}, {93.9693, 34.202}, ..., {98.4808, -17.3648}, {100., 0.}}.

Comment: @MarcoB I fixed the radius. I noticed that while writing the post but forgot to copy and past the new code to match the updated picture. That is why the diagrams have the correct radius but the code didn't. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 8):

```
rg1 = Circle[{0, 0}, 2];
rg2 = Circle[{0., 1}, 1.5];
pts=RegionIntersection[rg1, rg2] 
RegionPlot[{rg1, rg2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, pts}]
```

Point[{{-1.45237, 1.375}, {1.45237, 1.375}}]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for illustrative purposes:

```
i[{c1_, r1_}, {c2_, r2_}] := 
 Module[{r}, 
  If[c1 == c2 && r1 == r2, {}, 
   r = {x, y} /. 
     Solve[{({x, y} - c1).({x, y} - c1) == 
        r1^2, ({x, y} - c2).({x, y} - c2) == r2^2}, {x, y}, Reals]; 
   If[r === {x, y}, {}, r]]]
f[{c1_, r1_}, {c2_, r2_}, lim_] :=
 Module[{sol = Quiet@i[{c1, r1}, {c2, r2}]}, 
  Graphics[{Circle[c1, r1], Circle[c2, r2], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[sol], Text[c1, c1], Text[c2, c2], Blue,
    Arrow[{c1, c1 + r1 {-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}], 
    Text[Framed[r1, Background -> White], 
     c1 + r1 {-1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}/2],
    Arrow[{c2, c2 + r2 {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}], 
    Text[Framed[r2, Background -> White], 
     c2 + r2 {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}/2],
    Text[#, #, {-1.5, 0}] & /@ sol
    }, PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-lim, lim}, 2], Axes -> True, 
   GridLines -> Transpose[{c1, c2}]]]
f[{{0, 0}, 50}, {{85, 0}, 70}, 170]
Manipulate[
 f[{c1, r1}, {c2, r2}, 2], {c1, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, 
  Locator}, {{c2, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}, {r1, 0.1, 
  2}, {{r2, 1}, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to add the alternative answer for you.

```
C1 = Table[{50*Cos[\[Theta]*Degree], 
 50*Sin[\[Theta]*Degree]}, {\[Theta], 1, 360}] // N;
C2 = Table[{70*Cos[\[Theta]*Degree] + 85, 
 70*Sin[\[Theta]*Degree]}, {\[Theta], 1, 360}] // N;
```

> To show in graphic, you can use:

```
ListPlot[{C1, C2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

> For the intersection, you can follow program below:

```
equation1 = x^2 + y^2 == 50^2;
equation2 = (x - 85)^2 + y^2 == 70^2;
solutionMax = Solve[{equation1, equation2 && y > 0}];
solutionMin = Solve[{equation1, equation2 && y < 0}];

coordMax = solutionMax[[All, All, 2]]
coordMin = solutionMin[[All, All, 2]]
{{965/34, (35 Sqrt[1599])/34}}
{{965/34, -((35 Sqrt[1599])/34)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to do it with `Region` functionality. However, if equations are the starting point, then the following could be a possibility.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq1 = x^2 + y^2 - 50^2;
eq2 = (x - 85)^2 + y^2 - 70^2;

etyp = (-h + x)^2 + (-k + y)^2 == r^2;

sol1 = SolveAlways[ eq1 == Subtract @@ etyp, {x, y}];
sol2 = SolveAlways[ eq2 == Subtract @@ etyp, {x, y}];

c1 = Circle[{h, k}, r] /. First@Pick[sol1, r /. allsol // UnitStep, 1]
c2 = Circle[{h, k}, r] /. First@Pick[sol2, r /. allsol // UnitStep, 1]
```

> Circle[{0, 0}, 50]

> Circle[{85, 0}, 70]

```
ContourPlot[{eq1, eq2}
 , {x, -60, 160}, {y, -80, 80}
 , MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]
 , Mesh -> {{0}}
 , MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, eq1], Function[{x, y}, eq2]}
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesStyle -> {{Gray, DotDashed}, {Gray, DotDashed}}
 , Epilog -> {
   Black, AbsolutePointSize[6]
   , Point@{RegionCentroid@c1
     , RegionCentroid@c2}
   
   , {Dashed, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}]
    , Arrow[CirclePoints[{Last@c1, π/2 - π/14}, 2]]}
   
   , {Dashed, Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}]
    , GeometricTransformation[
     Arrow[CirclePoints[{Last@c2, π/3}, 2], 0.01]
     , TranslationTransform[First@c2]
     ] (* end of GeometricTransformation *)
    }
   } (* end of Epilog *)
 ]
```

[image]